# Next.js/Vercel: Dynamic page generation is slow

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I work with Next.js and host my project at Vercel. Behind the website is WordPress, which delivers the data headless. Since there are a lot of pages, I generate to the build page not all (for a pagination the first three).

However, when I now click on a link that points to a page that has not yet been generated during the build, it takes a very long time to trigger the dynamic build process (at runtime). Shouldn't the fallback page be delivered immediately?

[image]

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await getPostsPaths(); // Generates the first three pages of the pagination

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: true
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps(props) {
    const globalData = await getGlobalData();

    const posttype = props.params.posttype;
    const slug = props.params.slug;

    const id = await getPostsId(`/${posttype}/${slug}/`); // Fetch the post id
    if (!id) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }

    const post = await getPostsSingle(id);

    return {
        props: {
            globalData,
            post
        },
        revalidate: 300
    }
}

export default function Page(props) {
    const router = useRouter();
    
    if (router.isFallback) {
        return (
            <>Loading...</> // This should delivered immediately
        )
    }

    return (
        // Page is generated here
    )
}
```

Where is the bottleneck? Shouldn't the fallback page be called much earlier?

Link: https://kaktuell-website.pechschwarz.dev/werkstoffe/seite/4/ (click on a link in the pagination).

Comment: Have you tried updating all the nextJS imports?

Comment: Do you mean all dependencies? They are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I checked your site and could not reproduce the issue.

If the functions `getPostsPaths`, `getGlobalData`, `getPostsId` and `getPostsSingle` are making network calls to fetch data, especially from WordPress, those calls might be taking a while. You might want to check if there are any latency issues or rate limiting on the WordPress API you're using.
Also, for me it looks like you have set the `revalidate` field to 300 seconds. This would mean that the generated page will be invalidated after 300 seconds and will be regenerated upon the next request. This shouldn't be a problem for the initial load but might have implications for frequent visitors (Which you are as the Developer probably are).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

If I understand correctly, the fallback page should be delivered first and meanwhile the data is fetched. Currently it takes about 5-10 seconds until the fallback page is delivered at all.